# Проблема с выводом кириллицы из SQL в CMD

Tags: python, cmd, sql

Мне нужно вывести из БД строку на кириллице. Кодировка ДБ win-1251.

Код следующий:

```
def checkfdbconnection():
    global db
    try:
        db = fdb.connect(dsn=gvar.dbhost, user=gvar.dbuser, password=gvar.dbpass)
        print "Connected to FireBird DB"
        try:
            cur = db.cursor()
            cur.execute("select CUSTOMER_NAME from CUSTOMER")
            results = cur.fetchall()
            for row in results:
                print row
            db.commit()

        except:
            print "Can't create DB"

    except:
        print "[ERROR] \t Could not connect ro FireBird DB"

checkfdbconnection()
```

Однако на консоль я получаю только:

```
('\xcd\xd6 \xce\xcc\xc7',)
('\xce\xce\xce1',)
('\xce\xce\xce2',)
```

Как быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> print '\xcd\xd6 \xce\xcc\xc7'.decode('windows-1251')
НЦ ОМЗ
>>> print '\xce\xce\xce1'.decode('windows-1251')
ООО1
>>> print '\xce\xce\xce2'.decode('windows-1251')
ООО2
```

Comment: Если я делаю: print row.decode('windows-1251')
то вместо русских букв выводится:
Can't create DB

т.е. с этим моментом что-то не так. Ошибку выдает.

Comment: При печати в консоль выдает ошибку что не создать БД? Занятно.

ну как минимум row это еще не строка tuple.

Попрбуйте  

    print row[0].decode('windows-1251')

Comment: Уберите try:except или укажите в except конкеретный тип ошибки. Ато он у вас и при делении на 0 будет Can't create DB говорить.

Answer (score 0):

```
db = fdb.connect(dsn=gvar.dbhost, user=gvar.dbuser, password=gvar.dbpass, charset='windows-1251')
```